# choosing xeon cpu for webhosting stack

Tags: dell, xeon

I'm planning to buy 2 new servers in order to create a HA cluster for a production enviroment featuring lamp stack through proxmox.

i'm between del r340 and dell r540
the first is feraturing an 8c16t e-2288g and the later an 8x16t silver 4215
after googling around i found out that the single thread performance(which as i understand is what i'm looking for in a webserver/sql/php application) of the e-2288g is significantly faster than the 4215.
what i don't understand is how the second maching is much more expensive than the first when the first processor is much faster than the second whicle at the same time both of them have 8 cores and 16 threads.

/me scratches head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel's market segmentation diluting its Xeon brand, mostly. The [E-2288G](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/193743/intel-xeon-e-2288g-processor-16m-cache-3-70-ghz.html) is code name Coffee Lake, positioned alongside the Core series for some reason.  [Silver 4215](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/193389/intel-xeon-silver-4215-processor-11m-cache-2-50-ghz.html) is a 2nd gen Xenon Scalable Processor, code name Cascade Lake.

Read the fine print on the memory supported, caches, integrated graphics, and other features. In particular, that E series is limited to 128 GB RAM.

If you cannot decide, get both, performance test both, and return one.

Yes, this is confusing. No one likes needing to make a table to make sense out of CPU models.

Comment: unfortunately where i live is impossible to just get both and then return one. I have already read the prints you recoemmended. as i understand the E series is limited in 128gb of ram and uses only 2 memory channels(with the memory bandwidth limited to 2 channels as well). What is you personal opinion about which will be faster for a lamp stack?

Comment: I am not going to give a recommendation, far too many variables in how your workload performs. Make your best effort at a capacity needs assessment; how much RAM will you need in the future? Ask your hardware sales person to pick one that fits the overall design you are going for.

Comment: If you're looking at the price/performance ratio, make sure you check out the EPYC line as well (R6515/R7515).

Comment: Thank you for this valuable information